# How to link css file to specific section of page without using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the process of writing a chrome extension for a specific web site. Web site has already obtained its own css. But my extension adds some content to the page. And I want a specific design - bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css - for that content. So I can't simply link my 2 .css files, because they begin affecting the whole page. I've seen `<style scoped></style>` but it afects all parent Nodes except mine. Using of `<iframe>` is impossible: I need content to be written in one page only. So what do I need? That's it:

```
`<body>
 <div>
  <!-- Here Some page code, that I must not affect with css -->
 </div>
 <div class="myclass" id="need_css">
  <!--Here is my HTML-content, which needs bootstrap css-->
 </div>
</body>`
```

Comment: if you are using django then it can be done

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD — In a Chrome Extension? (And I don't see how Django would help anyway).

Comment: Take a look at this answer...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568065/limit-the-scope-of-bootstrap-styles

Answer (score 2):

Write your CSS using a descendant combinator on every selector.

Comment: +1 for brevity, accuracy, and the requirement for the OP to learn CSS!