# CSS @import inside a class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to do the following:

```
.bootstrap-scope { 
  @import "bootstrap.min.css";
}
```

I know `bootstrap.min.css` is in the proper place because placing `@import "bootstrap.min.css";` at the top of the css page works fine.

Anyways, the point is to be able to scope out what is affected by bootstrap. I would like bootstrap to only be applied to the enclosing div

```
<div class="bootstrap-scope">
...
</div>
```

Any ideas? This seems like it should be straightforward.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568065/limit-the-scope-of-bootstrap-styles) suggested to put the import inside a class.. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can't use an import statement this way. Your syntax is not valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot `@import` inside a CSS rule. `@import` statements must be declared outside any selectors.

#### From [the MDN page on @import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import):

> The `@import` CSS at-rule allows to import style rules from other style sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, except `@charset` rules; as it is not a nested statement, it cannot be used inside conditional group at-rules.

You would have to write such a thing in LESS or SASS, and preprocess it into CSS.

Your linked question suggests creating a LESS file that import Bootstrap's LESS code, and then compile that to CSS.

Comment: so... how would I accomplish this? [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568065/limit-the-scope-of-bootstrap-styles) suggested this exact solution..

Comment: @starvator That answer uses LESS, a preprocessor that can produce CSS from LESS code, such as Bootstrap's source LESS. This cannot be done with pure CSS.