# jquery datatables from datatables builder into react component

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, datatables

I've been trying to get [jQuery datatables](https://datatables.net/) to work in a react component. My app doesn't use bootstrap but I want to use it for my tables so I've scoped [bootstrap to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46435221/1628984) so i can use it in a div without affecting the rest of the application.

I read the following article [Integrating React and Datatables — not as hard as advertised](https://medium.com/@zbzzn/integrating-react-and-datatables-not-as-hard-as-advertised-f3364f395dfa), but the article presents a use case that is more basic than I think many `jQuery datatables` users use. `npm datatables` doesn't give you access to extensions (search, [scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/), [button functions](https://datatables.net/reference/button/), etc), and everything that comes without the extensions is easy enough that you might as well use an existing react table like [primereact](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact), [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table), [griddle](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle), [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid), [reactabular](https://github.com/reactabular/reactabular), [fixed-data-table](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table), or [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).

These offer many options but when tested, had at least 1 or more problems that prevented it from being easily adopted and use all the features needed. Some have issues i think I could help fix after I'm more seasoned with react, but I'm not there yet. I've used `jQuery datatables` in many production environments without any problems. It's a major sticking point moving to react.

So after weeks of searching and testing and trying to work through bugs, I'm back to trying to bring `jQuery datatables` into my react app. I realize it's not the "react way" but based on the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) it's possible and there's a proper way to approach it. I don't need it to react with anything outside of its container or `div` i place it in.

Using the [builder](https://datatables.net/download/) is the recommended way to download `datatables` so you can get your customized components. I'm also downloading rather than using the CDN because this is a local app and needs to work when there is LAN but no WAN access. I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and I tried to download datatables from [here](https://datatables.net/download/) to a folder in my project and had the following problems:

- hot-reload started taking forever (>1min)
- the page itself was moving at a crawl
- extensions didn't seem to be working (could have been locked up?)

How do you use `jQuery datatables` in a react app while still being able to use the `datatables extensions` and without killing the hot-reload for `create-react-app`? Can anyone provide a working example?

***Update***
Apparently `jQuery datatables` has made some major updates since the last time I tried to use their builder and now it includes a way to `npm install` the extensions too. I'll post a github of a working solution if i find one before someone else can update.

***Update***
Here is a [github](https://github.com/jtlindsey/jquery_datatables_in_react) i made of a react version that is partially working and a basic html/js/css version that is fully working. The readme tells what is working and not working. Can anyone show me why this not working properly?