# Is there any techniques which I can use to preserve old style and apply new style in web forms?

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

I have an old application created in webforms with visual basic. Now user wants to migrate that application to new UI which is using bootstrap and modern styling. But initially just want to apply side navigation bar and upper navigation bar and preserve old pages with old styling and show it in the new container.

I have shadow dom in my mind, but the compatibility issue is there using that for ie.

I want some suggestions about how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this answer
[Limit the scope of bootstrap styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568065/limit-the-scope-of-bootstrap-styles)

basically you can set bootstrap to only apply to items under a certain css class.

in your case you could set the side navication bar and upper navigation bar to this new class for example `class="use-bootstrap"` and then set bootstrap to limit its scope to elements under that class.