# Exclude Bootstrap styling from certain routes in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, sass, single-page-application, vue-router

I have a single-page vue 2 app made with the cli-tool. Most of my routes use Bootswatch (Bootstrap) styling. But one shouldn't at all. This is only a problem because the Bootstrap  affects the `body` and `html` styles and generally messes with the other styling. The route shouldn't use Bootstrap gets affected even when I `@import` the Bootstrap in a `scoped` `<style>` only to the routes that should use it. This happends if I first visit the Bootsrap routes and then to the isolated one. How should I go about doing this so that one of my routes is completely isolated when it comes to styling? If it's impossible or very impractical, suggest other ways of doing this. If this weren't a single-page-app this would be easy. But I'd prefer it be one.

Answer (score 4):

I succeeded in encapsulating bootstrap import within a class called 'bootstrap-inside' and assigning it to the #app (Index route for example) div that is supposed to be styled with Bootstrap.

```
   .bootstrap-inside {
      @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
   }
```

From now on, if you want to use bootstrap, you just have to use .bootstrap-inside in your component/view/layout.

I would suggest creating a view layout for your no-bootstrap pages and set your route to extends that layout (i can give you the solution for this too if you want).

I can mention this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49914269/5418615) of another thread about limiting the scope of bootstrap styling in case you go through unexpected bootstrap behavior.

Comment: That worked need to add `bootstrap-inside` class to any wrapper that will use bootstrap classes

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I know for this is to manually reset every css property for a given selector.

You could add an id / class to the root element of your page, and explicitly reset all css properties for all its childs. It would override the default bootstrap styles, but not remplacing its classes though.

Here's a class that would reset every css property: [reset css for a div #15901030](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

It's not super convenient but it should work!